# cannot set relation phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, relational-database

I have a question. I try to create an relation in my databse:
[image]

I want to set id in my suppliers column to my foreign key of suppliers_id in my orders column.

But I get the error shown in the yellow field.
the foreign key is set to null but even when I disable that option it still gives an error.

Hope someone can help

here is my table definition:

```
===Database inventory_test

== Table structure for table mutaties

|------
|Column|Type|Null|Default
|------
|//**id**//|int(11)|No|
|product_id|int(11)|No|
|aantal|int(11)|No|
|date|timestamp|No|CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
|omschrijving|varchar(255)|No|
== Table structure for table orders

|------
|Column|Type|Null|Default
|------
|//**id**//|int(11)|No|
|ordernummer|varchar(255)|No|
|product_id|int(11)|No|
|aantal|int(11)|No|
|omschrijving|varchar(255)|No|
|supplier_id|int(11)|Yes|NULL
|geleverd|tinyint(1)|No|0
|date|timestamp|No|CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
== Table structure for table products

|------
|Column|Type|Null|Default
|------
|//**id**//|int(11)|No|
|merk|varchar(190)|No|
|model|varchar(190)|No|
|threshold|int(11)|No|
== Table structure for table suppliers

|------
|Column|Type|Null|Default
|------
|//**id**//|int(11)|No|
|naam|int(11)|No|
```

Comment: Please add your table definitions as text to the question.

Comment: @P.Salmon done hope you can help

Comment: Your database tables contain data which are preventing the foreign key constraint from being added. You need to make sure the data in the tables is correctly linked

Comment: @NadirLatif I know but I dont know why and what data

Comment: If you post the data and table structure, we can check the problem. Also which columns do you want to link

Comment: @NadirLatif hi, I have added my whole sql: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/636b16611e352636d034390e2955181b20190718083533/920519 you can download it here. I want to in my suppliers column the id link it to my orders column supplied_id and then on delete set null and then on update cascade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the orders column contains data with value **0** in **suppliers_id** column. But **0** value does not exist in the id column of suppliers table, so when you try to create the foreign key it gives an error.

You need to set the **suppliers_id** column in orders table to null and then add the foreign key. To set the suppliers_id to null run this query: `update orders set supplier_id=null`. Also see this tutorial on [MySQL Foreign Key](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-foreign-key/)